# Фильтрация элементов в DOM по множеству параметров javascript

Tags: javascript, массивы, сортировка, dom, фильтрация

Добрый вечер.

Есть вот такой массив объектов:

```
[
    {type: "sex", val: "boy"}, 
    {type: "sex", val: "girl"}, 
    {type: "age", from: "", to: 6}, 
    {type: "age", from: 6, to: 18}, 
    {type: "size", from: "", to: 35}, 
    {type: "size", from: 36, to: 55}
] (6)
```

Мне нужно вывести элементы DOM по нему (Где все значения из массива соответствуют значениям элемента). Сам элемент выглядит так:

```
<div class="filter-item" data-sex="girl" data-age="10" data-size="40">
```

Элементы в массиве могут добавляться или убавляться, значения тоже меняются.

На данный момент я сделал вывод по полу:

```
params.forEach( function( el, i ) {

    if( el.type == 'sex' ) {

        $( '.filter-item[data-'+el.type+'="'+el.val+'"]' ).show();

    }

} );
```

Дальше, если я делаю вывод по возрасту, то элементы перебивают друг друга и получаеться 'каша'.

Помогите составить алгоритм для вывода всех этих параметров.

Comment: _На данный момент я сделал сортировку по полу:_ - а где сортировка? ты же просто показываешь все у которых тип _sex_

Comment: @Grundy видимо таки фильтрация имелась в виду, а не сортировка. Ибо даже критериев сортировки не приведено.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Берем в цикле каждый из элементов и проверяем его на соответствие установленному фильтру.
Проверить корректность работы фильтрации можно, комментируя некоторые из строк массива `filterObj` (у вас он настроен на "показывать всё)

```js
var filterObj = [
    {type: "sex", val: "boy"}, 
    {type: "sex", val: "girl"}, 
    {type: "age", from: "", to: 6}, 
    {type: "age", from: 6, to: 18}, 
    {type: "size", from: "", to: 35}, 
    {type: "size", from: 36, to: 55}
];

// проверяем каждый из DOM-элементов на удовлетворение условиям
$('.filter-item').each(function() {
  // сборка данных элемента для удобства манипуляций
  var sex = $(this).data('sex');
  var age = +$(this).data('age'); // приводим к Number
  var size = +$(this).data('size');
  var checked = {sex:false, age: false, size: false}; // объект для записи данных проверок
  
  for(var i =0; i < filterObj.length; i++) {
    var fEl = filterObj[i]; // сокращение для элемента фильтра
    // совпадение по полу
    if(fEl.type == 'sex' && fEl.val == sex) {
      checked.sex = true;
    }
    // совпадение по возрасту
    if(fEl.type == 'age') {
      if(fEl.from == '') {
        fEl.from = 0; // фиксим диапазон
      }
      if(fEl.from <= age && fEl.to >= age) {
        checked.age = true;
      }
    }
    // совпадение по размеру
    if(fEl.type == 'size') {
      if(fEl.from == '') {
        fEl.from = 0;
      }
      if(fEl.from <= size && fEl.to >= size) {
        checked.size = true;
      }
    }
  }
  // выводим, если все ссовпадения сработали
  if(checked.sex && checked.age && checked.size) {
    $(this).show();
  }
});
```

```css
.filter-item {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="filter-item" data-sex="boy" data-age="12" data-size="46">Мальчик, возраст 12, размер 46</div>
<div class="filter-item" data-sex="girl" data-age="1" data-size="43">Девочка, возраст 1, размер 43</div>
<div class="filter-item" data-sex="girl" data-age="8" data-size="40">Девочка, возраст 8, размер 40</div>
<div class="filter-item" data-sex="girl" data-age="1" data-size="2">Девочка, возраст 1, размер 2</div>
<div class="filter-item" data-sex="girl" data-age="2" data-size="16">Девочка, возраст 2, размер 16</div>
<div class="filter-item" data-sex="girl" data-age="15" data-size="28">Девочка, возраст 15, размер 28</div>
<div class="filter-item" data-sex="boy" data-age="13" data-size="48">Мальчик, возраст 13, размер 48</div>
<div class="filter-item" data-sex="boy" data-age="5" data-size="54">Мальчик, возраст 5, размер 54</div>
<div class="filter-item" data-sex="girl" data-age="4" data-size="10">Девочка, возраст 4, размер 10</div>
<div class="filter-item" data-sex="girl" data-age="4" data-size="19">Девочка, возраст 4, размер 19</div>
<div class="filter-item" data-sex="girl" data-age="7" data-size="24">Девочка, возраст 7, размер 24</div>
<div class="filter-item" data-sex="boy" data-age="15" data-size="15">Мальчик, возраст 15, размер 15</div>
<div class="filter-item" data-sex="girl" data-age="5" data-size="32">Девочка, возраст 5, размер 32</div>
<div class="filter-item" data-sex="girl" data-age="13" data-size="48">Девочка, возраст 13, размер 48</div>
<div class="filter-item" data-sex="girl" data-age="14" data-size="28">Девочка, возраст 14, размер 28</div>
<div class="filter-item" data-sex="girl" data-age="15" data-size="11">Девочка, возраст 15, размер 11</div>
<div class="filter-item" data-sex="boy" data-age="8" data-size="9">Мальчик, возраст 8, размер 9</div>
<div class="filter-item" data-sex="boy" data-age="16" data-size="7">Мальчик, возраст 16, размер 7</div>
<div class="filter-item" data-sex="boy" data-age="10" data-size="9">Мальчик, возраст 10, размер 9</div>
<div class="filter-item" data-sex="girl" data-age="16" data-size="29">Девочка, возраст 16, размер 29</div>
```

Comment: Благодарю. Я не указал выше, нужно что-бы даже по одному параметру была фильтрация. Т.е. можно указать только ПОЛ, без возраста и размера и фильтр должен работать.

Comment: Тогда вам предварительно нужно проверять `filterObj` и на основании его формировать `checked`

Answer (score 2):

Для фильтрации от одного параметра (метод выше работает при включенных всех параметрах) немного дополнил код:

```
function someFilter() {

    $( '.filter-item' ).hide();

    if( params.length ) {

        $( '.filter-item' ).each( function() {

            let sex     = $(this).data('sex'),
                age     = +$(this).data('age'),
                size    = +$(this).data('size'),
                checked = { sex: false, age: false, size: false },
                clicked = { sex: true, age: true, size: true };

            params.forEach( function( fEl, i ) {

                if( fEl.type == 'sex' ) { clicked.sex = false;

                    if( fEl.val == sex )
                        checked.sex = true;
                }

                if( fEl.type == 'age' ) { clicked.age = false;

                    fEl.from = fEl.from != ''? fEl.from: 0;

                    if( fEl.from <= age && fEl.to >= age )
                        checked.age = true;

                }

                if( fEl.type == 'size' ) { clicked.size = false;

                    fEl.from = fEl.from != ''? fEl.from: 0;

                    if( fEl.from <= size && fEl.to >= size )
                        checked.size = true;
                }

            } );

            if( ( checked.sex || clicked.sex ) && ( checked.age || clicked.age ) && ( checked.size || clicked.size ) )
                $(this).show();

        });

    }

}
```